# Читать сообщения публичных каналов

Tags: telegram

Мне нужно в приложение читать сообщения некоторых публичных каналов, как например это происходит https://tlgrm.ru/channels/tech
Как я понял бот для этого дела не подойдет.
Нужно использовать client api, но везде что с каналом методы связаны везде нужен channel_id но где его взять я не знаю, у меня есть только имена каналов, а как по ним получить его id я не нашел такого метода.
Может кто-то уже делал что-то подобное?

UPD 
Подсказали решение в этой ветке https://stackoverflow.com/a/46529402/4927579

Comment: Бот очень даже себе подойдёт.

Comment: https://api.telegram.org/bot111:222/sendMessage?chat_id=@channelName&text=123  Вернет в том числе ID канала.

Comment: А разве бот может отправлять первым сообщение, я вроде читал что он только отвечать может на запросы, или все таки может?

Comment: Я про то, что только отвечать нигде ничего не видел в официальной документации. Если Вы видели - поделитесь :)

Comment: Попробовал ботом, пишет что бот не входит в канал.{"ok":false,"error_code":403,"description":"Forbidden: bot is not a member of the channel chat"}

Comment: Так нужно как то мембером стать. Об этом в вопросе ни слова :)

Comment: :)) не им как я понял стать не получиться ботом, ток если тебя создатель группы добавит, что конечно исключено, прямо тупик какой-то

Comment: Есть же открытые каналы. С ними как то проще. Или Вам закрытые нужны - тут уж никак.

Comment: В том то и дело что открытые нужны и не выходит, я для @teleblog пробовал, он же вроде открытый.